# Deleting Folders From A List in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I found VBA code which automatically delete empty folder from a list. But when folders have files within it, code skip delete for those folder but I want to remove all folders whatever it has files or empty.

Excel files is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1haN2BmRAS_KosFkD6UoyGhlVltYrDiSp/view

```
Sub DeleteFolders()

Dim Folder As Range
Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = Range("DeleteFolderPath").Value

On Error Resume Next

For Each Folder In Range("DeleteFolderNames[Folder Name]")
    RmDir FolderPath & "\" & Folder.Text
Next Folder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Kill` statement to delete the files in the folder, then do `RmDir'

```
Sub DeleteFolders()
    Dim Folder As Range, Dim FolderPath As String

    FolderPath = Range("DeleteFolderPath").Value

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Folder In Range("DeleteFolderNames[Folder Name]")
        Kill folderPath & "\" & Folder.Text & "\" & "*.*"
        RmDir FolderPath & "\" & Folder.Text 
    Next Folder
End Sub
```